# What is the layout of the initial data block of an NFC Forum Tag 3 card?

Tags: nfc, ndef

Can anyone explain the format of the first data block of a NFC forum tag 3? I'm trying to emulate tags and therefore need to understand the format, I've found resources on the NDEF data blocks but I can't find anything on the initial block. When I write to the PN532, I get the output ```0x10, 0x0c, 0x08, 0x00
0x3f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
0x00, 0x0f, 0x01, 0x00
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x73```
on the first chunk, but I am not quite sure how to decipher this. Can anyone explain/direct me to a resource on how this first chunk is encoded?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Type 3 NFC Forum Spec has some detail on the Initial System Information Blocks http://apps4android.org/nfc-specifications/NFCForum-TS-Type-3-Tag_1.1.pdf